# Getting 'Error: missing revert data in call exception' when calling safeSdk.executeTransaction()

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

Once the transaction is signed by all the owners, I'm trying to execute it with the executeTransaction() safeSdk method but the transaction is being reverted and it returns me this error =>

```
Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (data="0x", transaction={"from":"0xFe48Eb58b0B889E57844F50B4da7B1886F680C4F","to":"0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E","data":"0xa0e67e2b","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32000,"message":"invalid opcode: INVALID"}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.6.8)
```

fetching the pendingTx from the safeService.getPendingTransactions() method.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
  const handleExecution = async () => {
    const safeTransactionData = {
      to: pendingTx.to,
      value: pendingTx.value,
      data: pendingTx.data || "0x",
      operation: pendingTx.operation,
      safeTxGas: pendingTx.safeTxGas,
      baseGas: pendingTx.baseGas,
      gasPrice: pendingTx.gasPrice,
      gasToken: pendingTx.gasToken,
      refundReceiver: pendingTx.refundReceiver,
      nonce: pendingTx.nonce,
    };
    const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(
      safeTransactionData
    );
    pendingTx.confirmations.forEach((confirmation) => {
      const signature = new EthSignSignature(
        confirmation.owner,
        confirmation.signature
      );
      safeTransaction.addSignature(signature);
    });

    console.log("safe Transaction: ", safeTransaction);

    const executeTxResponse = await safeSdk.executeTransaction(safeTransaction);
    const receipt =
      executeTxResponse.transactionResponse &&
      (await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse.wait());
  };
```

When I'm executing the transaction in the Safe app frontend it work, but not when calling the executeTransaction() method.

Chain: Rinkeby
Safe Version: 1.3.0
Ethers: 5.6.9